# Can every problem that uses recursion be solved using iteration?

Tags: recursion, iteration

We all know iterations and recursions are a powerful thing in programming. But this doubt always troubles me whenever I write an iteration or recursion. Can every recursive problem solved using iteration and vice-versa? We can avoid efficiency for simplicity. Only thing is **is it possible for all?**

Comment: I believe by using the stack data structure, yes, since you can just simulate the recursion stack.

Comment: Oh what I can't upvote your comment... Thanks